# ¿Cómo hago que los números tengan dos dígitos?

Tags: javascript

Usando este código solo el "01" me sale con "0" los demás solo un dígito

¿Cómo haría para que todos los números tengan 2 dígitos (00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09)

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var text = "";
var x = 1
var i=("0"+x).slice(-2);
while (i < 13) {
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Le estas agregando el cero afuera del while (se transforma en string), dentro del while se le suma uno y se convierte nuevamente a número perdiendo el cero a la izquierda.

Iterando sobre X y agregando el cero a I sólo para presentación

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var text = "";
var x = 1
while (x < 13) {
  var i=("0"+x).slice(-2);
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
   x++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra opción sin slice ni I

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var text = "";
var x = 1;
while (x < 13) {
    text += "The number is " + (x<10?"0":"") + x + "<br>";
   x++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh raios no me di cuenta 
Muchas gracias!!.

Answer (score 1):

Te propono también esta solución

> Las variables inicio y fin me van a ayudar para delimitar el recorrido
>   que va a hacer el while y también para que con ayuda del condicional
>   if else se verifique que número se pasa en cada iteración y aggregarle
>   el cero de ser necesario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultado">
  
</div>
<script>
    let inicio = 1
    let fin = 13
    
    let lienzo = document.querySelector("#resultado")

    while(inicio <= fin){
      if(inicio < 10){
        lienzo.innerHTML += "0"+inicio+"<br />"
      }else{
        lienzo.innerHTML += inicio+"<br />"
      }
      inicio++
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Donde como vez dentro del bucle while hago con un if else la
>   observación si el número es menor a 10 para agregarle el cero a la
>   izquierda

También dentro del uso de INNERHTML puedes hacer uso de las template strings para mostrar el resultado del modo siguiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultado">
  
</div>
<script>
    let inicio = 1
    let fin = 13
    
    let lienzo = document.querySelector("#resultado")

    while(inicio <= fin){
      if(inicio < 10){
        lienzo.innerHTML += `The number is: 0${inicio} <br />`
      }else{
        lienzo.innerHTML += `The number is: ${inicio} <br />`
      }
      inicio++
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olvídate de ese algoritmo, simplemente debes utilizar la función `padStart()` para rellenar con el caracter `"0"` al comienzo de la cadena hasta completar 2 caracteres:

```js
var text = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
  text += `The number is ${i.toString().padStart(2, "0")}<br>`;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: nota: no anda en IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility

Comment: En el link que has colocado está el polyfill.para navegadores que no lo soportan de forma nativa. Simplemente incluye también ese código

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres más portabilidad, puedes implementar esta función<sup>1</sup>:

```
function paddy(num, padlen, padchar) {
    var pad_char = typeof padchar !== 'undefined' ? padchar : '0';
    var pad = new Array(1 + padlen).join(pad_char);
    return (pad + num).slice(-pad.length);
}
```

Recibe como parámetros:

- `num`, el número con el que se va a trabajar
- `padlen` que sería el tamaño total del valor en dígitios
- `padchar` (opcional), que sería el carácter de reemplazo, para usar otro caracter diferente de cero (por defecto).

Veamos algunas pruebas:

```js
var text = "";
var x = 1
var i=("0"+x).slice(-2); //¿Por qué no i=1?
while (i < 13) {
    text += "The number is " + paddy(i,2) + "<br>";
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;


/*Prueba con otro relleno*/
text = "";
i=1;
while (i < 13) {
    text += "The number is " + paddy(i,4,'*') + "<br>";
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo-otro").innerHTML = text;

/*Prueba con más ceros*/
text = "";
i=1;
while (i < 13) {
    text += "The number is " + paddy(i,7) + "<br>";
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo-mas").innerHTML = text;


function paddy(num, padlen, padchar) {
    var pad_char = typeof padchar !== 'undefined' ? padchar : '0';
    var pad = new Array(1 + padlen).join(pad_char);
    return (pad + num).slice(-pad.length);
}
```

```html
<h3>Demo 1</h3>
<div id="demo"></div>
<hr />
<h3>Demo con otro relleno</h3>
<div id="demo-otro"></div>
<hr />
<h3>Demo con más ceros</h3>
<div id="demo-mas"></div>
```

---

### Fuente

<sup>1</sup> La función [es una de las respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744576/5587982) a la pregunta *How can I pad a value with leading zeros?* en Stackoverflow en inglés, aunque no es la respuesta aceptada, [este benchmark](http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad) demuestra que es la más eficaz.