# Obtener hora con el formato hh en vez de un solo caracter

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy obteniendo la fecha y la hora con  este código de GAS:

```
var now     = new Date();
var year    = now.getFullYear();
var month   = now.getMonth();
var day     = now.getUTCDate();
var hora    = now.getHours();
var minutos = now.getMinutes();
var segundos= now.getSeconds();
var fechaTicaje = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hora + ":" +  minutos + ":" + segundos;
hojaRegistro.getRange(ultimoRegistro+1,1).setValue(fechaTicaje);
hojaRegistro.getRange(ultimoRegistro+1,2).setValue(estadoActual);
```

Pero al obtenerlo en la hoja de cálculo de Google lo obtengo así: `"  2021-5-17 19:9:4  "`
y querría obtenerlo así `"   2021-5-17 19:09:04    "` (con los dos ceros).

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

En Google Apps Script hay una forma más sencilla (menos líneas de código) y más precisa ya que toma devuelve los datos de fecha hora con base en la zona horaria especificada:

```
var fechaTicaje = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'UTC-5','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo hago que los números tengan dos dígitos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/175820/65)
- [¿Cómo obtener una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY con Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/181354/65)

Comment: Mil Gracias Rubén.

Comment: No hay de que @PAbloMol. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)